# Extension method returns InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, exception, extension-methods

I'm trying to learn how to use extension methods and have created my own. Now I tried to run my code, but Visual Studio gave me an error that I had an unhandled InvalidCastException, so I handled it and tried to run it.

I had to return null in catch block, so I had another unhandled exception, printed that as well.

Now when I try to run this code I the output is

`InvalidCastException 
NullReferenceException`

[Generic conversion method throw InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760051/generic-conversion-method-throw-invalidcastexception) Tried the solution as found here by adding (dynamic) to the cast, same result.

*Note, I have a java background, not C#*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Reeks r = new Reeks();
        IEnumerable<int> selectie = r.TakeRange(10, 1000);
        try
        {
            foreach (int i in selectie)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("selectie: {0}", i);
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NullReferenceException");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

static class MyExtension
{
    public static Reeks TakeRange(this Reeks r, int start, int end)
    {
        try
        {
            return (Reeks)r.Where(i => i > start && i < end);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException) { 
            Console.WriteLine("InvalidCast"); return null; 
        }
    }
}


public class Reeks : IEnumerable<int>
{

    public Reeks()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int start = 2;
        yield return start;
        for (; ; )
        {
            int nieuw = start * 2;
            yield return nieuw;
            start = nieuw;

        }

    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }


}


}
```

Comment: On which line? Did you debug your code?

Comment: On both the try-bodies, started at `return (Reeks)r.Where(i => i > start && i < end);`

Comment: type of `reeks.Where` is not `Reeks` any more. `Reeks` is `IEnumerable<int>` but every `IEnumerable<int>` is not `Reeks`.

Comment: As it is defined now, `Reeks` is a class that produces a list that is hard coded. It is not designed to hold custom data. Can you explain what is the intent of this class?

Comment: For your Java-knowing mind: Consider an extension method as a "magic custom instance method" declared in the class specified by the first `this` parameter of the extension method. In case of the `Where` method, that's `IEnumerable<T>`. Look up the extension method's signature and you'll see it also returns `IEnumerable<T>`, without any guarantee of a more specific type. (Other than that the two `T` will obviously be the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your static method so it returns an `IEnumerable <int>`, take a look at this:

```
static class MyReeksExtension {
        public static IEnumerable <int> TakeRange(this IEnumerable<int> r, int start, int end) {
            return r.Where(i => i > start && i < end);
        }
    }
```

Make sure your 'selectie' is also of this type:

```
IEnumerable<int> selectie = r.TakeRange(10, 1000);

        foreach (int n in selectie)
            Console.Write("{0}; ", n);
```

No problem, I had to find help too :P

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the return value of the `Where` call in the `try` block to type `Reeks`:

```
return (Reeks)r.Where(i => i > start && i < end);
```

However, there is no method anywhere called `Where` that actually returns an object of type `Reeks`. That code calls `Enumerable.Where`, which returns some kind of `IEnumerable` implementation, but definitely not your own type.

You have to either implement a new (extension or instance) method named `Where` that can be called on a `Reeks` object and also returns a `Reeks` object. Or you could simply accept the fact that `Where` does not return a `Reeks` and simply expect an `IEnumerable<int>` instead.

Comment: But Reeks implements IEnumerable<int> wouldn't this solve that problem? Else I'll rewrite the Where

Comment: In Java, `ArrayList<Integer>` also is a `List<Integer>`, but you still can't cast it to `LinkedList<Integer>` just because they implement the same interface.

Answer (score -1):

you should change the following line 
`return (Reeks)r.Where(i => i > start && i < end);`
to 
`return (Reeks)(r.Where(i => i > start && i < end).ToList().AsEnumerable());`

The where clause returns an enumerator which should be converted to a list. Also, you can try the `skip` and `take` in linq for replacement to the above code snippet.

Comment: Cannot convert List to Reeks

Comment: @Ivaro18, seems that you have a infinite loop, do review the code

Comment: This will not work at all. because the question is totaly wrong. two `IEnumberable<int>` are not same